# Make an adittion in php

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a  problem with my addition : 
So I have this code :

```
                $total = 0;
                foreach(getHistory($this->id) as $history){
                    $aHistoryFilter['date']                 = $history['date'];
                    $aHistoryFilter['ls']                   = $history['ls']);
                    $aHistoryFilter['montant']              = $history['montant'];
                    $aHistoryFilter['total_montant']        = $total+$history['montant'];
                    $aHistory[] = $aHistoryFilter;

                }
                return $aHistory;
```

So I want to save in `total_montant` the last value, but not work and I don't understand why...Can you help me please ? Thx in advance

Comment: Try to put $aHistory[] = $aHistoryFilter; Before the $aHistoryFilter['date']

Comment: you never update `$total`, so effectively you're doing `total_montant  = 0 + montant`, which boils down to `total_montant = montant`

Answer (score 2):

You should also do:

```
$total  = $total + $history['montant'];
```

otherwise you do not add anything (since `$total=0;`)

So you get:

```
           foreach(getHistory($this->id) as $history){
                $aHistoryFilter['date']                 = $history['date'];
                $aHistoryFilter['ls']                   = $history['ls']);
                $aHistoryFilter['montant']              = $history['montant'];
                $aHistoryFilter['total_montant']        = $total+$history['montant'];
                $total  = $total + $history['montant'];
                $aHistory[] = $aHistoryFilter;

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

update your code to be:

```
$total = 0;
foreach(getHistory($this->id) as $history){
$aHistoryFilter['date']                 = $history['date'];
$aHistoryFilter['ls']                   = $history['ls']);
$aHistoryFilter['montant']              = $history['montant'];
$total       = $total+$history['montant'];
$aHistory[] = $aHistoryFilter;

}
$aHistoryFilter['total_montant'] = $total ;
```

because in your code you `$history['montant']` to `$total` but you didn't assign the result to `$total`

Comment: You are a few seconds late ;P

Comment: @BasvanStein there is no problem. I will up vote you

Comment: let me return the favour, after all great minds think alike.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            $total = 0;
            foreach(getHistory($this->id) as $history){
                $aHistoryFilter['date']                 = $history['date'];
                $aHistoryFilter['ls']                   = $history['ls']);
                $aHistoryFilter['montant']              = $history['montant'];

                // this adds the $history['montant'] to the $total
                $total                                 += $history['montant'];
                // this adds the $total to your variable
                $aHistoryFilter['total_montant']        = $total;

                $aHistory[] = $aHistoryFilter;

            }
            return $aHistory;
```